# Functions & Cellular automata

Tags: functions, cellular-automata

Let x = number of live neighbors of a cell 
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
live & \textrm{if}\ x = 3\\ 
live & \textrm{if}\ x = 4\\ 
dead & \textrm{otherwise}\\
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$$f(1) = dead$$
$$f(3) = live$$
$$f(4) = live$$
$$f(5) = dead$$

Given that the outputs aren't numbers, is this still mathematically sound?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Functions represent a relationship between 2 (not necessarily identical) sets.

You can talk about the function whose input in the name of a town, and whose output is the distance that you are from it.